# attributeBindings and classBindings not appending to <div> with component helper in Ember 2.1?

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I have a widget dashboard app where the individual widgets are displayed using the component helper. A template ends up looking like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{component model.displayComponent model=model}}
  </div>
</div>
```

A `Widget` instance will return a path for the `displayComponent` like: `widgets/category/specific-widget`.

What I'm finding, in Ember 2.1, is that the `attributeBindings` and `classBindings` defined on the component are not being applied. And I *think* they were being applied back in Ember 1.13.

In other words, in 1.13 think a component defined like this:

```
// app/components/widgets/category/specific-widget.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  model:      null,
  classNames: [ 'widget-content' ],
  attributeBindings: [ 'style:style' ],
  style:      Ember.computed.readOnly('model.contentHeight')
});
```

I would get a `<div id="ember..." style="height:300px" class="ember-view widget-content">...</div>`. Now I simply get the default `<div id="ember..." class="ember-view">...</div>`.

Am I mistaken about the old behavior? If not, is there a way to make this work the old way?

P.S. I'm unable to find the documentation for the component helper anywhere. Is that on the ember.js site?

**EDIT**: developer error... I had my path to my widget templates named differently (plural) than my widget code. For example: my template was `app/templates/components/widgets/categories/widget.hbs` but my widget code was `app/components/widgets/category/widget.js`. Because Ember inserts a component code in there by default, there was no error thrown. If I had made the mistake in the other direction an error would have been thrown.

Comment: check this out may help you. http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/

Comment: That link isn't really relevant to the question, I think you wanted http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/. `attributeBindings` should still work as it always has, my guess would be your computed `style` property is not returning a value. Can you verify that `model.contentHeight` exists in that context?

Comment: I believe it is correctly generating a `Ember.Handlebars.SafeString` from the model. I wrapped the component helper with a `<div style={{model.contentHeight}}>` and that has the style applied.  That's my current solution until I figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: PEBKAC error... I had my widget templates path .hbs named differently than than the .js files. So the template was rendering but there was no component behind it. Arrghhh.... convention over configuration is usually great but it can't save a developer from himself.

Comment: Ah ok. I just made a dummy app to mimic yours and was just going to say it worked for me. Glad you figured it out.